# Load gltf file into a three.js scene with a html <input>

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

I have been trying to load an gltf object to a *three.js* scene by uploading it from a HTML input tag.

I need to select a specific file from the client computer, then show it on the website, ZIP it an then send it to a multimedia management server (cloudinary)

My Code (I removed camera settings to make the question sorter though):

```js
const gltfUploader = document.getElementById('gltf-uploader');
const imageUploadbar = document.getElementById('img-upload-bar');

gltfUploader.addEventListener('change', async (e) => {

    let file = e.target.files[0];

    console.log(typeof file);

    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(file, 
        function(gltf){
          scene.add(gltf.scene);
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
```

and here is the html:

```html
<input type="file" id="img-uploader">
<progress id="img-upload-bar" value="0" max="100" style="width: 100%"></progress>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a FileReader to read the File as text first. And instead of using `loader.load()`, which loads gltf from an url, use `loader.parse()` that loads gltf from data (a string/text in JSON format).

According to the docs https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader You have to give `loader.parse()` the arguments data, path, onLoad and onError. I am not sure if you can omit the path argument, so I included it. It says data should be an ArrayBuffer, but in the source it shows you can put in a string..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

```
gltfUploader.addEventListener( 'change', async (e) => {

    let file = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    // This is code that runs after reader.readAsText() finishes
    reader.onload = function ( gltfText ) {

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        loader.parse( gltfText, '', function( gltf ){

          scene.add( gltf.scene );
          renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }, function( errormsg ){
            console.error( errormsg );
        });    

    });

    reader.readAsText( file );
```

Answer (score -1):

In the Docs they say that the glTF asset to parse, as an ArrayBuffer or JSON string, but try ArrayBuffer and I hope it works.

Code that works for me with glb and gltf models

```
document.querySelector("#inputSelector").onchange = e =>  {
    let file = e.target.files[ 0 ];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
    reader.onload = gltfText => {
        let loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.parse( gltfText.target.result, '', (gltfData) => {
            scene.add(gltfData.scene)
        }, 
        errMassage => { console.error(errMassage) } )
    }
}
```